# using awk inside expect program

Tags: command-line, awk, expect

I'm using the command below to merge file1 and file2 to get file3:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$1; next} {$(NF+1) = a[$NF]} 1' file2 file1 > file3
```

When I use this command inside bash script using expect I'm getting the file3 empty (the command is working manually).

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash Menu Script Example

outputMME="$( expect <<END
spawn ssh atndn@x.x.x.x
expect "Password: " { send "password\r" }
expect "# " { send "bash\r" }
expect "$ " { send "cd /tmp/DPE_CORE/home/atndn/eniq/\r" }
expect "$ " { send "awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1; next} {\\\$(NF+1) = a[$NF]} 1' file2 file1 > file3\r" }
END
)"

echo "$outputMME"
```

File1:

```
 471808241 29164840 1 10001 156197396 
 471722917 21067410 1 31001 135961856 
 471941441 20774160 1 7001  180995072 
 471568655 29042630 1 15001 157502996 
 471524711 20716360 1 4001  180226817 
 471873918 29583520 1 2001  128567298 
 471568650 29042631 1 15002 157502910
```

File2 :

```
610146 156197396 
531101 135961856 
704011 180226817 
502216 128567298 
707012 180995072 
615246 157502996 
685221 157502910
```

File3 :

```
471808241 29164840 1 10001 156197396 610146 
471722917 21067410 1 31001 135961856 531101 
471941441 20774160 1 7001  180995072 707012 
471568655 29042630 1 15001 157502996 615246 
471524711 20716360 1 4001  180226817 704011 
471873918 29583520 1 2001  128567298 502216 
471568650 29042631 1 15002 157502910 685221
```

Comment: What is the point of wrapping the expect program inside a bash here document? since you are redirecting the awk output to file3, what are you expecting to be captured in `$outputMME`? You have at least 2 issues: preventing `expect` from expanding things you don't want it to and preventing `bash` from expanding things you don't want it to.

Comment: also asked at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/348085/4667 -- StackOverflow would have been the best place for this question.

Comment: Voting to leave open as lo longer cross posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement steeldriver's comment:

```bsh
outputMME="$( 
    expect <<'END'
        #....^ [1]
        spawn ssh atndn@x.x.x.x
        expect "Password: " { send "password\r" }
        expect "# " { send "bash\r" }
        expect "$ " { send "cd /tmp/DPE_CORE/home/atndn/eniq/\r" }
        expect "$ " { 
            send {awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1; next} {$(NF+1) = a[$NF]} 1' file2 file1 > file3}
            #....^ [2]
            send "\r" 
        }
        expect "$ " { send "exit\r" }
        expect "# " { send "exit\r" }
        expect eof
END
)"
```

1. you need to quote the heredoc terminator (`'END'`) so that bash does not do variable (and other) substitutions in the document.
2. you need to properly quote the awk command so that expect does not substitute the awk variables.